# Trouble with Python if/else statement

Tags: python

I'm sure the answer to this is embarrassingly easy, but I cannot for the life of me figure this one out. I have this code and if I just have the if statement it works perfectly, but when I add the else it stops working. What on earth am I doing wrong?!

```
import wmi
import win32api
c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while True:
    new_process = process_watcher()
    if(new_process.Caption == "java.exe"):
         win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Java has started, did you mean for this to happen?', 'Warning', 0x00001000)
    else:
         win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Not Java', 'Warning', 0x00001000)
```

Comment: What does "stops working" mean?

Comment: It just "stops working"? Or is there an error message? If so, please share it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using tabs for indentation, and I think you have an indentation error.
Use `python -tt scriptname.py` to detect.

Comment: you're right...I got inconsistent use of tabs, but I don't see what is wrong.

Comment: @user1419579: Configure your editor to use spaces for indentation, not tabs. Re-indent every line (by hand if necessary). You have a tab character on the first `win32api` line, but since it's a copy-paste here and not the original file, I cannot tell if that's your only problem.

Comment: @user1419579, whitespace defines block structure in Python. But the width of a tab character is undefined, so code that combines spaces and tabs may have ambiguities in its block structure. Use one or the other -- preferably spaces.